# Date.getTime() in Next.js returns weird numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, react-hooks

I am trying to make a page transition in Next.js. As the transition is slower than the page load, I need to calculate the missing time for the animation to finish. The transition should last at least 2 seconds, 1s for a fade in of the loading screen, 500ms so that the loading screen stays a little, and 500ms for it to exit.

I am actually trying to achieve this using `new Date.getTime()` and getting the amount of time passed since the animation started.

I've tried using the following code to check that the code is correct:

```js
function testDateValues() {
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var animDuration = 1500; // In milliseconds

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(animDuration - (new Date().getTime() - startTime));
    }, 1000);
}
```

This function prints the time missing after 1 second, which is 500ms (is prints a number between 498-502 but it is correct).

However, when I translate this code to Next.js, I get numbers like `-19604`, `-60418`, and numbers that have got nothing to do with the remaining animation time.

The code is the following (reduced):

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

import { useState } from 'react';

export default function LoadingScreen() {
    const router = useRouter();    
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [loadingStartTime, setLoadingStartTime] = useState(new Date().getTime());

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleStart = () => {
            console.log("Loading started");
            setLoading(true);
            setLoadingStartTime(new Date().getTime());
        };
        const handleComplete = () => {
            console.log("Loading completed");
            console.log(1500 - (new Date().getTime() - loadingStartTime));
            setTimeout(() => {
                setLoading(false);
            }, 1500 - (new Date().getTime() - loadingStartTime));
        };

        router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleStart);
        router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleComplete);
        router.events.on("routeChangeError", handleComplete);

        return () => {
            router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleStart);
            router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleComplete);
            router.events.off("routeChangeError", handleComplete);
        };
    }, []);

    return {loading && (<div>Loading</div>)}
}
```

That loading screen is in the `components/layout.jsx` file.

```js
import LoadingScreen from "./LoadingScreen";

export default function Layout({ children }) {
    return (
        <>
            <motion.main>{children}</motion.main>
            <LoadingScreen />
        </>
    )
}
```

The loading screen does not even show for a while. There is no page transition.

Why does almost the same code return so different values? (and why -19604 and not 500?)

Comment: You start with a fixed number (`animDuration = 1500`) and roughly every second subtract a number that gets larger every iteration (by roughly 1000). This appears to be doing exactly what you asked it to do

Comment: Eg iteration #1 `1500 - (~ 1000) = ~ 500`, iteration #2 `1500 - (~2000) = ~ -500`, etc

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand. Where is the iteration?

Comment: `setInterval()` runs your function every second. Each time it runs is an [_iteration_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iteration)

Comment: It is not `setInterval()`, it is `setTimeout()` which runs only once

Comment: Err your code literally has `setInterval`

Comment: I've already edited it. My mistake. Although for the context of what I'm trying to do I thought it was pretty clear

Comment: I've re-opened your question but it still needs clarity. The first snippet of code doesn't appear related to the second one at all. When you say you _"get numbers"_, what does that mean? Where are you observing these numbers? Is it from the second `console.log()` in `handleComplete`?

Comment: @Phil If this is a duplicate at all, it's about [the useState set method not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `loadingStartTime` is initialised when the component loads, and that constant value is what the code in the effect will use. The `setLoadingStartTime` call [has no effect on the closed-over `const` value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/1048572), all it does is cause the component to re-render. This will not cause the effect to run again however.

There are various ways to solve this:

- don't use a state for `loadingStartTime` but simply a mutable variable in the effect handler scope:

  ```
  export default function LoadingScreen() {
      const router = useRouter();    
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

      useEffect(() => {
          let loadingStartTime = Date.now();
  //      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          const handleStart = () => {
              console.log("Loading started");
              setLoading(true);
              loadingStartTime = Date.now();
  //          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          };
          const handleComplete = () => {
              console.log("Loading completed");
              console.log(1500 - (Date.now() - loadingStartTime));
              setTimeout(() => {
                  setLoading(false);
              }, 1500 - (Date.now() - loadingStartTime));
          };

          router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleStart);
          router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleComplete);
          router.events.on("routeChangeError", handleComplete);

          return () => {
              router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleStart);
              router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleComplete);
              router.events.off("routeChangeError", handleComplete);
          };
      }, []);

      return {loading && (<div>Loading</div>)}
  }
  ```
- don't use a state for `loadingStartTime` but a constant that is initialised when the transition begins:

  ```
  export default function LoadingScreen() {
      const router = useRouter();    
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

      useEffect(() => {
          const handleStart = () => {
              console.log("Loading started");
              setLoading(true);
              const loadingStartTime = Date.now();
  //          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

              const handleComplete = () => {
                  console.log("Loading completed");
                  console.log(1500 - (Date.now() - loadingStartTime));
                  setTimeout(() => {
                      setLoading(false);
                  }, 1500 - (Date.now() - loadingStartTime));
              };
              router.events.once("routeChangeComplete", handleComplete);
              router.events.once("routeChangeError", handleComplete);
          };

          router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleStart);

          return () => {
              router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleStart);
          };
      }, []);

      return {loading && (<div>Loading</div>)}
  }
  ```

  Notice this will keep the complete and error handlers even after the component has unmounted, which may or may not be desirable - or not matter at all.
- use two separate effects with proper dependencies:

  ```
  export default function LoadingScreen() {
      const router = useRouter();    
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
      const [loadingStartTime, setLoadingStartTime] = useState(Date.now());

      useEffect(() => {
          const handleStart = () => {
              console.log("Loading started");
              setLoading(true);
              setLoadingStartTime(Date.now());
          };
          router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleStart);

          return () => {
              router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleStart);
          };
      }, []);

      useEffect(() => {
  //  ^^^^^^^^^
          console.log("New loadingStartTime", Date(loadingStartTime));
          const handleComplete = () => {
              console.log("Loading completed");
              console.log(1500 - (Date.now() - loadingStartTime));
              setTimeout(() => {
                  setLoading(false);
              }, 1500 - (Date.now() - loadingStartTime));
          };
          router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleComplete);
          router.events.on("routeChangeError", handleComplete);

          return () => {
              router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleComplete);
              router.events.off("routeChangeError", handleComplete);
          };
      }, [loadingStartTime]);
  //      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

      return {loading && (<div>Loading</div>)}
  }
  ```